# How can I test ansible roles used to install applications in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, kubernetes-helm

I am writing roles to install helm charts and roles to install kubernetes yaml configs. I would like to test all this, for example, using molecule or something similar, but there is a problem in hosting the entire kubernetes cluster for this, and I would somehow like to get away from this, or at least minimize costs. As a result, my question is: are there any best practices for this kind of testing, such as bypassing the installation of a kubernetes cluster and using, for example, mock helm or mock kubectl, or is it possible to install a kubernetes cluster by spending as little as possible time (for example, using kind, minikube, etc.)?

I tried setting up a kubernetes cluster with kind and writing a set of tasks to bring that cluster into the state required to test the ansible role, but I'm wondering if there's a way to speed up the process.

Comment: If you are stepping on the field a third party application or integration, the best is possibly to use a mock, indeed.

Comment: indeed you can use either `minikube` or cloud providers which offer managed Kubernetes clusters, e.g. [Linode](https://www.rokpoto.com/how-to-create-kubernetes-cluster-on-linode-using-cli/) which provisions the cluster rather fast